# SwiftUI animation glitch with search bar and Scroll view (iOS 16.4 / SwiftUI 4)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I have a simple page with a search bar and some views below it in a scroll view, when I tap on the search bar, the keyboard push up animation is overlapping the search bar and glitching. Please see the gif below. Has anyone faced this before?

[image]

**Following is my code**

```
struct CustomTabBar: View {
    @State var searchText = ""
    var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                ForEach(data, id: \.self) { d in
                    box
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Search")
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
        }
    }
    
    var box: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 75, height: 50)
            .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the SwiftUI version and the iOS version to better simulate this on our side.

Comment: @PierreJanineh iOS 16.4 / SwiftUI 4. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**You need to animate view changes.** To do that you need to:

1. Read `@Environment` variable `.isSearching`.
2. Detect view changes by calling `.transaction(_ transform:)`.
3. Assign an animation to the transaction (only when environment variable `.isSearching` is true or when search is dismissed).

### `ContentView.swift`

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var searchText = ""
    @State var searching = false
    @State var toggledSearch = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            SearchableView(searching: $searching)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Search")
        .searchable(text: $searchText,
                    placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
        .transaction {
            if searching || toggledSearch {
                $0.animation = .easeInOut
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    toggledSearch = !searching
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> In order to avoid hiding search placement when dismissing search, set the placement to `.navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always)` in `searchable(text:placement:)`

### `SearchableView.swift`

```swift
struct SearchableView: View {
    @Binding var searching: Bool
    @Environment(\.isSearching) var isSearching
    var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { d in
                box
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: isSearching) { newValue in
            searching = newValue
        }
    }
    
    var box: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 75, height: 50)
            .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}
```

**To read `@Environment` variable.**
Use `onChange(of:perform:)` to update the value of `searching` variable.

> Reading `@Environment` variable `.isSearching` can only be done here, you cannot read it from the parent.

Comment: Hmm this gives some unexpected animations when appearing and the search bar hides unexpectedly.

Comment: Thanks! it works to a certain extent. But when you hit cancel, the animation is sloppy. Do we really have to animate this manually? Isn't it already handled? I think this might be a bug..